# Java using AWS SDK with S3 object versions

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I am using the AWS S3 SDK to upload objects to various s3 providers. The uploads are multi-part. On completion of an upload if the bucket is configured for versioning then my expectation is that CompleteMultipartUploadResult will contain the versionId. This expectation does not hold true when the s3 provider is Google. All other tested providers return a valid version-id.

Further if I issue a ListVersionsRequest() and iterate through the version summaries then for non Google buckets I retrieve the versions as expected BUT for Google the versionSummary is empty.

Any advice on how to obtain versionIds using AWS on Google platform - Thanks

Simplified sample code:

```
CompleteMultipartUploadResult result = s3Client.completeMultipartUpload(completeRequest);
            
expiration = result.getExpirationTime();
versionid = result.getVersionId();
 
ListVersionsRequest versionRequest = new ListVersionsRequest();
versionRequest.setBucketName(destBucketName);

VersionListing versionListing = null;            
do {
        versionListing = s3Client.listVersions(versionRequest);
        for (S3VersionSummary versionSummary:versionListing.getVersionSummaries())
        {
            log.debug("key:" + versionSummary.getKey() +
                            " size:" + versionSummary.getSize() + 
                            " date:" + versionSummary.getLastModified() +
                            " latest:" + versionSummary.isLatest() +
                            " versionID:" + versionSummary.getVersionId() + ")");

        }
        versionRequest.setKeyMarker(versionListing.getNextKeyMarker());
    versionRequest.setVersionIdMarker(versionListing.getNextVersionIdMarker());
    } while (versionListing.isTruncated()); `
```

Using the Google web interface I can see the versions in the buckets - confirming that versioning is enabled and being actioned but I cannot retrieve versioning information programatically

Comment: Maybe report a bug or raise a support ticket with Google Cloud. It will probably depend on their definition of "S3 compatibility".

Comment: Thanks for the response -  I have opened ticket 271559073 with Google

Comment: Have yet to receuve a resokution to the case opened against Google COS. I would question the commitment of Google to AWS compatibilty